# MUI DialogTitle Not Responding to SCSS Styling

Tags: typescript, sass, fonts, material-ui

I am trying to apply a google font to the text within a Material-UI DialogTitle.

App.module.scss:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=EB+Garamond:ital,wght@1,600&display=swap');
$garamond: 'EB Garamond', serif;

.DialogTitle {
  font-family: $garamond; 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

App.tsx:

```
import s from "./App.module.scss";
import { Dialog, DialogTitle } from '@mui/material'
...
  <Dialog>
    <DialogTitle classes={{ root: s.DialogTitle }}>
      Title
    </DialogTitle>
  </Dialog
```

The font stylings do not apply. However, when I add a `color` styling to `.DialogTitle`, it does change the color of the text. Why would this be the case?

Answer (score 1):

The root styling of the MUI component will override the custom styling unless the custom styling is given higher specificity. I achieved this by using multiple classes:

```
.Dialog.TitleText {
  font-family: $garamond; 
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 20px;
}

import cn from 'classnames';
<Dialog>
  <DialogTitle classes={{ root: cn(s.Dialog, s.TitleText) }}>
    Title
  </DialogTitle>
</Dialog
```